# Why are eye coordinates not detected with FaceDetectionListener for Android

Tags: java, android, face-detection

I am working on an Android app that does face and eye detection using the FaceDetection API for Android.  I am able to detect and draw rectangles around faces but however I cannot figure out why all my eye coordinates are getting set to (0,0).

Reading this 
[documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Face.html), I see that the eye detection is not supported on all devices but it says that the Point objects are set to null, not (0,0) so I don't understand what is going on here.

Here is my FaceDetectionListener:

```
private List<Rect> faceRects;
private Point leftEye;
private Point rightEye;

@Override
public void onFaceDetection(Camera.Face[] faces, Camera camera) {
    if (faces.length > 0) {
        faceRects = new ArrayList<Rect>();

        for (int i = 0; i < faces.length; i++) {
            int left = faces[i].rect.left;
            int right = faces[i].rect.right;
            int top = faces[i].rect.top;
            int bottom = faces[i].rect.bottom;
            Rect uRect = new Rect(left, top, right, bottom);
            faceRects.add(uRect);

            leftEye = faces[i].leftEye; //***THIS IS (0,0) EVEN WHEN FACE IS DETECTED
            rightEye = faces[i].rightEye;
        }
    }
}
```

Why are my Points for eye coordinates getting set to (0,0). I am testing on a Galaxy S7 and I find it hard to believe that it doesn't support eye detection. I am open to a solution to this problem using OpenCV as well but I'd rather stick with the Android SDK since I can already detect the faces (if possible). Thank you for the assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all devices support all the face features.

As the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Face.html#leftEye) states for leftEye and most of the other fields:

> This is an optional field, may not be supported on all devices. If not supported, the value will always be set to null. The optional fields are supported as a set. Either they are all valid, or none of them are.

Only the Face.rect and Face.score fields are guaranteed to be included if face detection is supported by the device.

Comment: "may not be supported on all devices" is very vague. Is there any sort of list of supported devices?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  Camera2 API has explicit listing for https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#STATISTICS_INFO_AVAILABLE_FACE_DETECT_MODES but those only map to Camera1 if the camera2 hardware level is LIMITED or better; LEGACY-level will never list FACE_DETECT_MODE_FULL even if the old camera API has the optional fields populated.